# Vista cannot map network drive

Tags: windows-vista, networking, network-shares, drive-letter

As per subject, I'm not able to map a remote network drive to my Vista. I tested on an XP machine in the same network as mine and it's able to map the said drive, I also tried another Vista in the same network, but it's not able to map as well. So it's definitely the Vista.

Anyone can shed a light on this?

EDIT:
The error message was just generic Windows cannot access \\xx.xx.xx.xx\share_name

EDIT2:
Ok, after the error message appears, it actually asks me whether I want to diagnose. So I did and I got this:

[Window Title]
Windows Network Diagnostics

[Main Instruction]
"xx.xx.xx.xx" is not set up to establish a connection on port "File and printer sharing (SMB)" with this computer.

[Windows found a problem that cannot be repaired automatically] [Cancel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably has to do with LAN Manager authentication level.

If you have the full featured Vista (access to security policy gui) follow this
http://www.builderau.com.au/blogs/codemonkeybusiness/viewblogpost.htm?p=339270746

Otherwise you'll have to change the value in the registry
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LMCompatibilityLevel from a 3 to a 1

This applies to Win7 machines too when trying to browse XP / Samba shares.

Comment: I don't have LMCompatibilityLevel and I don't have secpol.msc as well =/ any other idea?

Comment: Ok nvm, I actually have LMCompatibilityLevel, changed to one but I'm still getting windows cannot access...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the workstation service is started and set for automatice startup. This is needed to access network shares.